# Alamofire server requests converts integer parameters to string

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have to send request having fields such as

```
id:1
```

Issue is that when I check apache logs I see that field is in form of

```
id:"1"
```

That is rather than having Integer 1 , I am getting String "1". Here is my code

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
        "viewModel":viewModel];
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + getToken(),
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
    Alamofire.request(setUrl(),method:.post,parameters:parameters,headers: headers).responseJSON{
        response in
        print("Response:\(String(describing:response.result.value))")

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            self.status = true;
            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                self.responseString = utf8Text
            }
            self.responseJSON = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
        case .failure:
            self.status = false;
        }
        completed()
    }
```

Before request is initiated , i have made sure that all required fields are in Integer. Other fields are string , hence I am using Dictionary of Type `[String:Any]`
What am I doing wrong? I need to make sure that integer fields remain integer.

Comment: you have to use NSNumber instead of Integer for making a request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting encoding to

```
JSONEncoding.default
```

worked perfectly for me.

The request can also be like

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: object, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

And works great with other types of methods too!

Answer (score 0):

*I Know this is a late reply, Surely it will help someone. I have also faced the same issue, and took couple of hours to figure it out.*

You need to set encoding in Alamofire request inorder to solve this issue.

**encoding: JSONEncoding.default**

So the request will be like

**Alamofire.request(setUrl(),method:.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{
        response in**